# RealmSwift not syncing with MongoDB what is missed in this code?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, realm

I'm using realm backend for my swiftui project and it's never been synced so if I add object it's appear locally but not appears in mongodb app service,
so if I try to add object it's appears in local but it doesn't appear in app service and if I fetch the data it fetches the local data only and the items in app service collection doesn't appear

can someone help me what is missed in my code and here's my code

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

let app: RealmSwift.App? = RealmSwift.App(id: "swift-app-azpkw")

@main
struct RealAgenApp: SwiftUI.App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if let app = app {
                AppContainer(app: app)
            } else {
                AuthView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct AppContainer: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var app: RealmSwift.App
    
    var body: some View {
        if let user = app.currentUser {
            let config = user.flexibleSyncConfiguration(initialSubscriptions: { subs in
                if subs.first(named: "Property") != nil {
                    return
                } else {
                    subs.append(QuerySubscription<Property>(name: "Property") {
                        $0.ownerId == user.id
                    })
                }
            })
            AppView()
                .environment(\.realmConfiguration, config)
        } else {
            AuthView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct AppView: View {
    
    @AutoOpen(appId: "APP_ID", timeout: 4000) var autoOpen
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = app?.currentUser // id: 637ceaf802e0885f39a06d71
        switch autoOpen {
        case .connecting:
            MessageView(message: "Connecting")
        case .waitingForUser:
            MessageView(message: "Waiting for user to log in...")
        case .open(let realm):
            HomeView()
                .environment(\.realm, realm)
        case .progress(let progress):
            LoadingView(progress: progress)
        case .error(let error):
            MessageView(message: error.localizedDescription)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import Realm
import RealmSwift

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @ObservedResults(Property.self) var properties
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(properties) { category in
            Text("Category")
        }
    }
}
```

Greetings

Comment: There's nothing in the question that writes any data to a synced realm. Also `@AutoOpen(appId: "app_id") var autoOpen` is the best syntax and you need to supply your actual *app_id*; it's not clear if that's being done. If there is code that writes data include it and check the Realm Console website to see if the data is making it to the server? Is the server configured correctly? Are there any errors in the error log? There's lots of things that could cause this issue so it a good idea to do some troubleshooting and gather data before posting questions. It will help us narrow the cause.

Comment: Also, do your Realm models actually have a propety named `Property`? As in this `subs.append(QuerySubscription<Property>(name: "Property")` and this `subs.first(named: "Property")`? Generally in programming property names are lower cased to distinguish them from Class, Structures and Enums, so check that as well.

Comment: yes bro the app id is in autoOpen and i just used a button to insert a dummy data in purpose to check the log and actually there's an error it says
`{
  "Property": {
    "6382f41774b157c648e29fef": "cannot write to table \"Property\" before opening a subscription on it"
  }
}`

I think I've issue in my 
`subscriptions.append(QuerySubscription<Property>(name: "Property")`

what's the name supposed to be ? a collection name or a property ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

after a long search and reconfiguration of the app service I've just realized that the issue was `initialSubscriptions` of `flexibleSyncCOnfiguration` not calling and also I reconfigure the schema rules in App service UI

here's my final config initialize

```
let config = user.flexibleSyncConfiguration(initialSubscriptions: { subscriptions in
  if let _ = subscriptions.first(named: "all-properties") {
     return
  } else {
     subscriptions.append(QuerySubscription<Property>(name: "all-properties"))
  }
}, rerunOnOpen: true)
```